# How to test dependencies between microservices?

Tags: microservices, continuous-integration, integration-testing

We have two microservices `A` and `B` that are developed inhouse.
`A` provides an API that `B` consumes.

Let's assume that `B` has some specific integration tests that ensure that `B` is compatible with `A`.

We want these test to be run whenever the developer team from `A` commits a change.

Currently each team has a separate `Jenkins` and with Jenkins-terminolgy we would like to trigger a particular stage in `B`-pipeline whenever `A` changes.

We don't think our scenario is possible with each team having a separate Jenkins. So we would like to evaluate other CI-Tools that maybe support our scenario.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to softwareengineering @ stackexchange and thanks for asking the question. Recommending specific tools is off-topic per our community guidelines. See also https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integration test should not be a stage in the B pipeline, because it depends not only on changes in B but also on changes in A.

The integration test should be a separate Jenkins job that can be triggered by both the pipeline of A and the pipeline of B.
If both teams share the same Jenkins master server, this should be easy to arrange.
If the teams have separate Jenkins master servers, you should setup one of them to accept remote build triggers (the one that will be executing the job) and the other (or both) to remotely trigger the integration test job.

Comment: That is possible but sounds complicated since AFAIK Jenkins doesn't out-of-the-box support the remote triggering of a job on a remote master. We could solve this with a custom `curl` in the pipeline but then the feedback of the build is not being send to the the triggering pipeline. And, additionaly, that separate Jenkins job also seems like overhead. So we are indeed looking for an alternative to Jenkins here.

Comment: There is a Jenkins plugin for triggering builds on a remote instance: https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/. To me, looking for alternative CI tooling because your current tool is missing an out-of-the-box feature feels like much more overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Didn't know this plugin. Do you have an idea how we could react to the result of the remote job? The `A` pipeline should stop (e.g. wait for manual confirmation) if that remote job fails.

Comment: From the documentation in that link, it looks like the default behaviour is to fail the pipeline containing that trigger if the remote job fails.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you again. That plugin seems like the best solution for us so far.